# How to remove the .undefined part from JSESSION cookie?

Tags: cookies, jboss, session-cookies

I have an application written in java running on JBoss server. The session  cookie of this application has a value like `shgfsg7we6rwrgbrhjw3.undefined`.

I have done a few research and found that it is the property of JBoss server. As a security concern I need to hide all the server information from public. A hacker having this knowledge can easily guess that the application is running on JBoss server.

What I am looking for is a method to remove the `.undefined` portion from the cookie.

Comment: see: https://developer.jboss.org/thread/201760?tstart=0

Comment: Thanks a bundle for this. :)